# How to prevent duplicate username and email and show message "username or email already exists when people register? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**How to prevent duplicate username and email and show message "username or email already exists  when people register**
i take php code screenshot in  below. please solve my problem.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY3Wj.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing the data in table in database you can introduce a primarily key in to user name column in the table where you store the data , the DB automatically takes care and will not allow you to add a duplicate row in the table.

Comment: @bluelight I think it should should throw an `intergrity error` when trying to add a username that already exits. Implement a try catch(or whatever is its equivalent in php) where you create new user.

Comment: Hello @BlueLight if introduce primary key in the table inside DB, as mentioned by  above you will receive 'integrity error' in data base layer,use $result from your code which is capturing the query result from database use the exception handling https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and try to show custom message 'User already exist'

Answer (score -1):

You can make a middleware and check if the given (by the user) username or e-mail is already created in the database